# I want to fill an array from a function with the components of a file in c

Tags: c

Hey I have the code below that I want to fill the dict array with the values of a file. Basically i get each line and then with the help of the four strtok functions I get the value that i want in and then i place that value on dictionary[i] so i can fill my array with all the string from the file but i get the following warning in compilation:

the error message:

```
warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   38 |                         dictionary[i] = strtok(NULL, "\t");
```

the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crypt.h>
void readDict(char dictionary[]);

void readDict(char dictionary[]) {
    
    int i =0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("dictionary/top250.txt" ,"r");
  if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error! opening file");
    exit(1);
  }
  char chunck[128];
  size_t len = sizeof(chunck);
  char *line = malloc(len);
  if(line == NULL){
      perror("Unable to allocate memory to buffer");
      exit(1);
  }
  line[0]='\0';
  while(fgets(chunck, sizeof(chunck), fp) != NULL){
      if(len - strlen(line) < sizeof(chunck)){
          len*=2;
          if((line = realloc(line, len)) == NULL){
              perror("Unable to reallocate memory to buffer.");
              free(line);
              exit(1);
            }
        }
        strcat(line, chunck);
        if(line[strlen(line)-1] == '\n'){
            
            char* one = strtok(line, "\t");
            char* two = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            char* three = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            dictionary[i] = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            i++;
            line[0]='\0';
        }
  } 
  fclose(fp);
    free(line);

}


int main(int arg_count, char *arg[]) {
    char dict[250];
    readDict(dict);
    int j=0;
    for( j=0; j<=250; j++){
        fputs(dict[j], stdout);
    }
    
    //Rest of the code
    
}
```

Comment: strtok returns a string.  dictionary[i] is a single character element

Comment: `fputs(dict[j], stdout);` You seem to assume `dict` can hold multiple strings. That is not the case. It can only hold one string as it is an array of single `char`.

Comment: `chunk` is not used except to get the size; one would be better just to directly `malloc(128)`.

Comment: Why do you free `line` -- then you have entirely dangling pointers in your `dictionary`?

Answer (score 0):

The C function `strtok` returns a `char *`, it's a *pointer* to a `char`. The thing here is that you send to your function readDict a `char *`, when you put an index to a `char *` its becomes a `char`, but you try to assign a variable of type `(char) dictionary[i]` to a `char *`.. coming from `strtok` return value !

```
dictionary[i] = strtok(NULL, "\t");
```

If you wanna make a table try to make a `char **`, remember you can't say a `char *` is equal to an other ! You have to say for each `char` is equal to an other `char`, with a while / for loop.

It's only an advice, but try to allocate your strings, table, ... with malloc `void *` function, this is only to have a clean code without memory leak, and do not forget to free them with the `free(void *)` function.

Good luck anyway !

Comment: Welcome Erwann and welcome to Stackoverflow. The community always appreciate well presented and detailed answers. You have a set of tools to make your answers more readable like using backticks like this, code blocks (4 spaces - gives highlighted syntax) and more. You can check out this interesting thread about syntax highlighting: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work